# cannot read property 'validator' of undefined in angular 2?

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic2, angular2-routing, angular2-template

How do you validate a form in Angular2? I am getting an error.

https://plnkr.co/edit/slhySWT0mJXkloGK1kfO?p=preview

```
<ion-navbar *navbar>
  <ion-title>
    Ionic 2
  </ion-title>
</ion-navbar>

<ion-content class="has-header">
    <form [ngFormModel]="loginForm" (submit)="login($event)">
            <ion-input stacked-label>
                <ion-label>Username</ion-label>
                <input type="text" ngControl="username">
            </ion-input>

            <ion-input stacked-label>
                <ion-label>Password</ion-label>
                <input type="password" ngControl="password">
            </ion-input>

            <div padding>
                <button block type="submit" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">Login</button>
            </div>
        </form>
</ion-content>
```

**the error**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'validator' of undefined
    at NgFormModel.ngOnChanges (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.15/angular2.dev.js:17240:73)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.ChangeDetector_FormClass_0.detectChangesInRecordsInternal (viewFactory_FormClass:86:59)
```

Comment: http://www.gajotres.net/ionic-2-how-o-create-and-validate-forms/2/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with ionic2, so something may be going on that I'm not aware of.  However, it looks like you aren't declaring or initializing your form controls in FormClass. Maybe try this:

```
export class FormClass {

  loginForm: ControlGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){
    this.loginForm = this.fb.group({
      'username': ['', Validators.required],
      'password': ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

}
```

you will also need to define a login method in the FormClass to handle the (submit) binding you've defined.